# Does webRTC drop out like webSockets on non-SSL connections

Tags: javascript, webrtc

For javascript: webSockets in my experience can drop out at any time with an unstable and non-SSL connection. I use reconnection via heart-beat checking.

Should I be concerned about webRTC having similar problems?

From my monitoring of webRTC, it seems more passive and only 'does stuff' when it needs to, and I've not experienced it losing connection yet.

I've read up on the usual sources such as the html5rocks.com indroduction and some API FAQ's and google searches but can't find any real-world info.

Currently I'm using peer.js

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC specification states that ICE must be used in order to allow peer to peer connections.
But also, during a WebRTC session (RTP media or DataChannel), the browser has several ice candidates and is monitoring that "connection" with periodic STUN requests.

If the connection ir dropped anyway, another candidate can be used and tested also with STUN requests.

So, you don't really need to worry about having a heart-beat-like mechanism for WebRTC.

Comment: Yep im using googles turn/stun server, if it checks periodically that sounds good - cheers. I'll continue to check but since I'm not live yet I can't confirm much.